# Jquery: String convert to number

Tags: jquery, string

I have problem with string in Jquery.
I have to convert for example '4444aaaa5555' string to '44445555'. I want to cut everything beside the numbers, is there a function for that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
myString = myString.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't have strict rules for string and int. (You don't need a C# thinking)

For deleting the letters and keeping the numbers, you can try this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/L5S7Q/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var oldprice = $("#price").html();
    var newprice = oldprice.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
    $("#price").html(newprice);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with javascript using regex

```
   var number = yourstring.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

This will get rid of anything that's not [0-9]

if you want to make it as function

```
  function getNumber(param)
  {
      return   param.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  }
```

you can acces this by

```
 var number =getNumber(yourstring)
```